# SELECT JOIN with conditional (OR) cross

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I need to do something like this (in MySQL), my attempts using UNION won't work until now.

In theory:

```
SELECT * FROM
tableA A

JOIN tableB B ON A.tableAId = B.tableAId

LEFT JOIN tableC C ON C.tableAId = A.tableAId

LEFT JOIN tableD D ON D.tableAId = A.tableAId

JOIN tableE E
ON (C.tableEId = E.tableEId OR D.tableEId = E.tableEId)
```

The expected result is crossing A with B, optional C with A, optional D with A and get the E result if its id is on C or D.

In order to know if the record found is from C or D, I'm using an IF checking if tableCId or tableDId are null.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I know but the query is really hard to understand, this is the 1% of the logic and data is really heavy. Can help a functional diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code will work.

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA A JOIN
     tableB B
     ON A.tableAId = B.tableAId LEFT JOIN
     tableC C
     ON C.tableAId = A.tableAId LEFT JOIN 
     tableD D
     ON D.tableAId = A.tableAId JOIN
     tableE E
     ON E.tableEId IN (C.tableEId, D.tableEId);
```

This will filter out rows that have no matches in C and D, as well as those whose matches in C/D are not in E.  I assume that is desirable.

Also, `OR` and `IN` can have a bad impact on `JOIN` performance, but you don't mention performance as a concern.

Comment: LOL!!! OMG!!! The real query is so intense that I never tried to simplify it in the example that I use here. (Also I found an error in the data). Anyway never thought about IN, I like it more than my approach because have several tables with those optional conditions. Thanks a lot Gordon!!! Yes, I know about the performance :( But I don't know if this can be improved without change the entire structure.